# Script cut last char

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

In razor view I use Html.EditFor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "SalaryEdit", @class = "form-control", onkeypress = "myFunction()" } })
```

Script

```
 function myFunction() {
                var source = $('#SalaryEdit');
                console.log($("input[id^='SalaryEdit']").val());
            }
```

When I type in EditorFor for example: 1,23. It shows me only 1,2. It always cut last char. What is the reason?

Comment: Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress` as `keypress` event represents a character __being__ typed. Additionally as you are using jQuery, use unobstrusive event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#SalaryEdit").on("keyup",function(){
   var  str=$(this).val().split('.');
   var val='';
   if(str.length>1)
     val =(str[1].length>1) ?str[0]+'.'+ str[1].substring(0, str.length-1):str[0]+'.'+str[1];
   else
     val =str[0];
   $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="SalaryEdit" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onkeypress event rather than the onkeypress. onkeyup will show you the value of the input after the user has finished entering text into it. keypress will show you the value of it at the time the user enters anything.